# How can I make these textfieds elastic?

Tags: css, responsive-design, elasticlayout

It is possible to make the textfields on the left fill all the gray space to the right in a elastic way using CSS?

[image]

Comment: Please can you share current code.

Comment: Read my answer below please. I've also created an example for you and it would be nice of you to reply.

Answer (score 1):

I did a jsFiddle example for you, demonstrating how you could do it.
It's not the most approriate way because it's not dynamic. For example, the `input` fields must have a `50%` width to fill in the space. 
If you decide to have 4 input fields, you'd have to change from `50%` to `25%`.

But have a look at the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/peduarte/FwxhT/

Another way to do this, would be using javascript to calculate the gap and do a calculation to apply the remainder to the inputs, but again, not a great thing to do...

Answer (score 0):

Try `<input type="text" style="width: 100%" />`